# Notification Icon on HoneyComb is Too Dim

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an Android app that uses the NotificationManager to inform the user of certain events.  When I call .notify(), the icon I specify is shown in the status bar.  It works fine on various Android 2.2 and 2.3 phones.  But on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.1 the notification icon on the status bar is so dim it can barely be seen.  I've seen one other app that has a similar problem, but all the other apps I'm using that do notifications look OK.  I've followed the Guidelines at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html, including creating Android 2.3+ style icons and putting them in the drawable-hdpi-v9, drawable-mdpi-v9, etc. folders.  The icons all look OK when I look at them on my development machine; they are the right colors and are not dim.  What could I be doing wrong that is causing my notification icon to be shown so dim on the Honeycomb status bar?

Comment: Did you by chance figure out how to get it to not dim?  I can't tell if that was your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there is updated documentation available at the android developers web site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Comment: This updated documentation provides exactly the information I needed.  Thanks!